# How to get a filename and set it as a property in Ant?

Tags: java, ant

I need to scan files in a folder and set property as file name in Ant so I can use it later.
For example, there's a test123.tar under Jenkins folder.  I need to use test*.tar to match this file and then set a property named "filename" to test123.tar
Is it possible to do it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

You could use [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) to convert a fileset into a list of files, then [loadresource](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) with a [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) to extract the single required value from the list.

```
<project default="test">

    <target name="test">

        <!-- read your fileset into a property formatted as a list of lines -->
        <pathconvert property="file.list" pathsep="${line.separator}">
            <map from="${basedir}${file.separator}" to=""/>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="test*.tar"/>
            </fileset>
        </pathconvert>


        <!-- extract a single target file from the list -->
        <loadresource property="file.name">
            <string value="${file.list}"/>
            <filterchain>
                <!-- add your own logic to deal with multiple matches -->
                <headfilter lines="1"/>
            </filterchain>
        </loadresource>

        <!-- print the result -->
        <echo message="file.name: ${file.name}"/>

    </target>

</project>
```

Output:

```
$ ls test*.tar
test012.tar  test123.tar  testabc.tar
$
$ ant
Buildfile: C:\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
     [echo] file.name: test012.tar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Verbose output:

```
$ ant -v
test:
[pathconvert] Set property file.list = test012.tar
[pathconvert] test123.tar
[pathconvert] testabc.tar
[loadresource] loading test012.tar
[loadresource] test123.tar
[loadresource] testabc.tar into property file.name
[loadresource] loaded 13 characters
     [echo] file.name: test012.tar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: `${file.separator}` can be replaced with `/` to simplify

Answer (score 1):

A combination of fileset (to search) and pathconvert will help.

```
<project name="SuperRoot" default="demo" basedir=".">
    <fileset id="afileset" dir="searchfolder" includes="**/test*.jar"/>

    <target name="demo" >
        <pathconvert property="result" refid="afileset" />
        <echo message="found : ${result}"/>
        <basename property="foo.filename" file="${result}"/>
        <echo message="found : ${foo.filename}"/>
        </target>
</project>
```